# nuxt/content2 parse markdown string runtime

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt-content

I have a basic Nuxt3 + @nuxt/content v2 setup. There is a .yaml file in the `content` folder that has fields whose values are markdown strings ( this file is produced by Netlify CMS) i.e:

```yaml
# content/post.yaml
title: Some title
body: Some **markdown** content
```

I can fetch the file using `queryContent`, but **what do I use to parse and render the markdown in those fields?**

The provided `<Markdown />` component seems to accept only parsed markdown in the format that is returned when `queryContent` is called on `.md` files. But I cannot find an API exposed by `@nuxt/content` to parse markdown string into that format runtime (i.e in my `useAsynData` hook ).